# Where is the settings.json file stored for Transmission?

Tags: transmission

I've bought a Raspberry Pi and I have managed to install xbian, samba and bittorrent (transmission).

All the fun showed up when I tried to upgrade the older version from the repo to the latest version - Transmission 2.77 - by [following the steps as mentioned on Ubuntu Help Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingTransmission).

**My question is - where is the *settings.json* file stored?**

I can download via command line with success - but I can't configure the settings file to allow the remote web interface... (I can only find the settings file which the previous version used).

Answer (score 9):

The file is stored here:

```
sudo nano /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json
```

Make sure you stop it first before editing

```
/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon stop
```

Comment: There are many recommendations out there but this seems to be the best way to do it. Stopping the daemon beforehand is indeed important else your changes will be overwritten by transmission-daemon when it shuts down.

Comment: From a config management POV, this behaviour sucks.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which user runs it but you can easily find all potential locations by running

```
sudo find / -name 'settings.json'
```

this may result with many settings.json (usually not) file if you have other services which created a similar filename somewhere for something other than transmissionbt. To overcome, you can run

```
sudo grep -rnw '/' -e 'download-dir'
```

to find files which contain "download-dir" string which exist in settings.json file of transmission-bt.

Refer to  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Transmission

If running Transmission under the username transmission, the configuration file will be located at /var/lib/transmission/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json.

If running Transmission under your own username, the configuration file will be located at ~/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json.